# .NET: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Tags: .net, validation

Can someone point me to a web-cast or tutorial/video that explains this new namespace and how I can use it to help validate data like user input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this (sorry, not visual):

[ASP.NET MVC Tip #43 – Use Data Annotation Validators](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-43-use-data-annotation-validators.aspx):

> In this tip, I demonstrate how to take
>   advantage of the validators from the
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
>   namespace in an MVC application. You
>   can take advantage of these validators
>   to validate form data before
>   submitting the form data into a
>   database.